# Bash: Odd behavior reading from STDIN in a loop

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, stdin

I observe a behavior that I don't undrestand and would like someone to shed some light on it.

I have two scripts, both read from STDIN.

Reading a sequence of numbers from keyboard ( 1 enter 2 enter 3 enter ... )

Script A prints "x" everytime

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE 
do      
    echo "x"    # this happens everytime 
    echo $LINE  # this is the only different line
done

output:

1
x
1
2
x
2
3
x
3
4
x
4
5
x
5
```

Script B prints "x" only the first time it reads LINE

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE 
do      
    echo "x"             # this happens only the first time
    awk '{print $LINE}'  # this is the only different line
done

output:

1
x
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
```

Can someone explain this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is still in its first iteration. `awk` is reading all successive input, not the `read` command. The `awk` statement is also not printing the value of a shell variable `LINE`, since it is not expanded inside the single quotes. Rather, `awk` sees that its internal variable `LINE` is undefined, and treats it as having the value 0. `awk` then prints the value of `$0`, which is the line that it reads from standard input.

Comment: Great answer, I swear I found this tricky situation by accident. It would make a good examination question for beginners, ha ha.

Answer (score 2):

awk took control of your stdin.  If you type the following on command line, you will see what happens.

```
awk '{print $LINE}'
```

Your ctrl-D will finish the stdin to awk and take you back into the while loop.

Comment: Great answer, I swear I found this tricky situation by accident. It would make a good examination question for beginners, ha ha.